# SQL LIKE not/^ operator and multiple characters

Tags: sql, sql-like

So.. I thought I knew mssql fairly well but this one query asked of me today has me perplexed.  Basically a piece of code somewhere uses the LIKE clause to determine how to filter certain values.  I must point out that this cannot be changed, we cannot modify the query to use NOT LIKE.  But what if that's what I want to do?  Consider this example:

```
select * from 
(
select '1.2A' as num
union
select '1.3A' as num
union
select '1.4A' as num
union
select '1.4B' as num
union
select '1.5A' as num
) as test
where num like '1.[^4]_'
```

Now.. how can the WHERE be modified to return everything except 1.4A?  You can't do [^4A] or even [^4][^A] for obvious reasons.  Is this something which is simply impossible to do without using NOT LIKE? Or am I missing something here and just too Friday'd up to realise it?

Comment: JUst out of curiosity why can;t you modify the query to use NOT like?

Comment: Because the code is in some other component.  Basically the only thing I can provide the code is the value for the LIKE clause as a string.  I could be naughty and inject some additional SQL: e.g.
String likeArg = "'%' AND ColName NOT = '1.4A'"
But I know for a fact that the column names are dynamic.. so screwed there too...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can only change the expression after LIKE, then you can't do this with simple LIKE.

You'd need NOT LIKE or OR at least. You'd need the matching power of Regular Expression which is not available easily in SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

Is the code SQL-injection safe? Because I see injection as the only way to do that. Usually, only `_` and `%` have a meaning in the `LIKE` operands.

Answer (score 0):

If it really is just the 4A you're looking to exclude, then:

```
select * from 
(
select '1.2A' as num
union
select '1.3A' as num
union
select '1.4A' as num
union
select '1.4B' as num
union
select '1.5A' as num
) as test
where num like '1.[0-9]_'
    and RIGHT(num,2)<> '4A'
```

Comment: I assumed OP is limited to a single "LIKE" based on comment